# Open PHP Dynamic Page response in Cordova Inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to open the response that I get from my PHP server in the In App Browser in a new window.

I am creating an app using Ionic and using PHP as a back end. I have full control of the php server.

I am making the ajax call like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
          $("#paybutton").click(function() {
                                var params = "projectpaymentoption=1197&id=",
                                usernamepay = window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
                                paymenturl = params + usernamepay;

                                $.ajax({
                                       type: 'POST',
                                       url: 'http://www.blabla.com/encode.php',
                                       data: $.param({"paymenturl": paymenturl}),
                                       success: function(output) {


                                       window.open('output','_blank','location=no','closebuttoncaption=Zurück');






                                       console.log(result);
                                       }
                                       });
                                });
          });
```

Now I want to open the **output** in a new inappbrowser windows.

The output i am throwing out is as follows

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once('includes/headers.php');
require_once('includes/connection.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<?php
include($filePath);
?>
```

It is a dynamically generated php page. An not an **url**.

How can I show this page in the inappbrowser

Comment: How do you open it with a normal browser ?

Comment: it's being opend as a response to a form post.. so i am sending some post data, depending on that data the response is generated.

Comment: You need to do it the same way. InAppBrowser take a URL at first parameter.